# How to get the Battery Charge Level specifically in mWh (not percentage) for Mac (Cocoa or C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, power-management

The title pretty much explains it all. I'm creating a mac app and I need the battery charge level **specifically in mWh** (not percentage). Would like to do it in C or Objective C preferably.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is a bit of code that directly answers my question which is getting the **Battery Charge Level in mWh.** It's not perfect, but it does the job.

```
 + (NSString* ) chargeInMWH 
  { 



CFMutableDictionaryRef matching , properties = NULL;
io_registry_entry_t entry = 0;
matching = IOServiceMatching( "IOPMPowerSource" );
entry = IOServiceGetMatchingService( kIOMasterPortDefault , matching );
IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties( entry , &properties , NULL , 0 );



NSNumber * voltage = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:1.0];
NSNumber * currentCapacity= [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:1.0];

voltage =  [properties objectForKey:@"Voltage"];    
currentCapacity =  [properties objectForKey:@"CurrentCapacity"];


int floatValue = [voltage intValue];
int floatValue2 = [currentCapacity intValue];
int answer = floatValue * floatValue2;

NSString *theCompleteAnswer = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",answer];


CFRelease( properties );
IOObjectRelease( entry );


return theCompleteAnswer;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't think the hardware has a way to report that.  It's going to change over time as the battery gets on in its life cycle, and all you *could* know at the outset is the nominal capacity of the battery when it was installed.

Comment: CoconutBattery (http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/) gets the current capacity and charge level in mAh.  Perhaps contacting the developer would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't help you, but I do know that the `ioreg` command line program can dump out all kinds of wonderful stats about your computer's battery, including design capacity, current capacity, and current charge level in mAh. (`ioreg -l` gives you really verbose output with all of this) If you can figure out what API *that* program uses, you could do the same.

Or you could just call the program from your app and capture the output.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276975/getting-iphones-battery-level/3277140#3277140) gives some details about using IOKit to get the mac battery level that might help you.

Comment: @drawnonward. Great answer! You should have posted it as an answer so I could have accepted it. I've taken the snippet that is placed in the Edit of your answer and ran it. Works just fine. Now what if I want to print just certain values of the properites, such as DesignCapacity. Thanks for the help!