# How to get UIDevice batteryLevel to provide status in 1% increments or finer

Tags: iphone, sdk, power-management

It seems the "default" data returned by UIDevice batteryLevel is in 5% increments. How do I get it to 1% or finer?

Comment: Wondered that too! - Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469549/iphone-calculating-battery-life

Answer (score 1):

The UIKit calls to retrieve Battery can only get a number better 0.0 to 1.0 with 0.05 steps which means 5% intervals. In order to get it with finer granularity you might have to jail break the device and setup something like [this](http://blog.coriolis.ch/reading-the-battery-level-programmatically/) but you might not be able to submit the app. Just in case, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276975/getting-iphones-battery-level) post, which might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna develop for jailbroken devices, you can take a look at [this](https://github.com/ethan605/ios-battery-stat) example